# How do I update values in a nested dictionary in python without getting error "dictionary changed size during iteration"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Python beginner here. The project I'm working on uses a nested dictionary of different business locations and their hours by day of week. It's formatted like this:

```
all_branch_hours = {
    'Branch 1': {
            'Sunday': '12:00-18:00',
            'Monday': '09:00-18:00',
            'Tuesday': '09:00-20:00',
            'Wednesday': '09:00-20:00',
            'Thursday': '09:00-20:00',
            'Friday': '12:00-18:00',
            'Saturday': '10:00-18:00'
    },
    'Branch 2': {
            'Sunday': '13:00-17:00',
            'Monday': '10:00-18:00',
            'Tuesday': '10:00-20:00',
            'Wednesday': '13:00-20:00',
            'Thursday': '10:00-18:00',
            'Friday': '13:00-18:00',
            'Saturday': '10:00-18:00'
    },
    'Branch 3': {
            'Sunday': '13:00-17:00',
            'Monday': '10:00-18:00',
            'Tuesday': '10:00-20:00',
            'Wednesday': '10:00-20:00',
            'Thursday': '10:00-20:00',
            'Friday': '13:00-18:00',
            'Saturday': '10:00-18:00'
    }
}
```

I want to generate a new dictionary where the hours are converted to lists of integers so that I can run a script later that checks whether or not a time is within open hours. For example the string "12:00-18:00" would become list [12,13,14,15,16,17].

Here's what I tried:

```
import copy
datetime_branch_hours = copy.deepcopy(all_branch_hours)

for key, value in datetime_branch_hours.items():
        for k in value.values():
             openhour= int(k[0:2])
             closehour= int(k[6:8])
             open_hour_range = list(range(openhour, closehour))
             value[k] = open_hour_range`
```

I've tried this which I though should work, but I keep getting "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration". I know that editing a copy can avoid this error, but I don't know how to do that with a nested dictionary. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't add/remove items in a dictionary while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong key for the inner dictionaries, causing addition of new keys while iterating. You need to iterate over the `items` of the inner dictionaries to get access to their true keys.

```
for key, value in all_branch_hours.items():
        for k, v in value.items():  # now k is truly key of inner dictionaries
            openhour= int(v[0:2])
            closehour= int(v[6:8])
            open_hour_range = list(range(openhour, closehour))
            value[k] = open_hour_range
```

Comment: Great! Thank you that worked. I was confused about how to update the keys/values, but your answer makes it all make sense. Thanks :)